# Update Note System field on a PUT request using Endpoint Rest API

Tags: acumatica

Hi I want to set the Note field as part of my PUT request when adding a new activity record in Advanced.

I have my custom endpoint setup and I can insert the activity record no worries except setting the Note system field doesnt seem to do anything?

Here is an example of my JSON for the request

```
{
"Note": "narrtion test five",
"Summary": {
    "value": "Test Task Status"
},
"Type": {
    "value": "W"
},
"ActivityDate": {
    "value": "2020-03-04T00:00:00"
},
"StartTime": {
    "value": "0001-01-01T15:00:00"
},
"Owner": {
    "value": "MATTMCD"
},
"Status": {
    "value": "Completed"
},
"CostCode": {
    "value": "0000"
},
"EarningType": {
    "value": "RG"
},
"Billable": {
    "value": true
},
"LabourItem": {
    "value": "LABOUR-MAT"
},
"Project": {
    "value": "PR00000001"
},
"ProjectTask": {
    "value": "TESTTASK"
},
"TimeSpent": {
    "value": "0:30"
},
"ActivityDetails": {
    "value": "narrtion test five"
}
```

}

Would appreciate some help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with "note" instead of "Note" ?

```cs
{
   "note": "narrtion test five",
   ...  
}
```